# check if two objects in array are adjacent based on property

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects as :

```
const arr = [{
        brand: 'merc',
        group: 'p4'
    },
    {
        brand: 'por',
        group: 'p8'
    },
    {
        brand: 'merc',
        group: 'p44'
    },
    {
        brand: 'bmw',
        group: 'p42'
    },
    {
        brand: 'cri',
        group: 'p88'
    },
    {
        brand: 'merc',
        group: 'p47'
    },
    {
        brand: 'bmw',
        group: 'p49'
    },
    {
        brand: 'ras',
        group: 'p34'
    },
    {
        brand: 'zen',
        group: 'p22'
    },
]
```

For this array I am trying to check if `brand : merc` and `brand : bmw` are adjacent to each other , in the above case it is true

I have been thinking to solve this by getting of both of these indexes and check them , but seems not that easy to do by this way ,

Though gave it a try but i can get index of only first appearance ,

```
    var bIndex = arr.findIndex(car => car.brand=="merc");
```

It would be great to know how this could be done ,any help is appreciated :) TIA

Comment: do you need only boolean value based on the condition? If so, you can make use of `some()`

Comment: @gorak yes , absolutely :)

Comment: `arr.some((k,i,self)=>k.brand=='merc' && self[i+1].brand=="bmw")`

Comment: @gorak What happens to `self[i+1].brand` when visiting the last element of the array? Looks like a nullref error to me.

Comment: @spender, yes may be we can put `conditional operator` here `self[i+1]?.brand`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
    {
        brand: 'merc',
        group: 'p4',
    },
    {
        brand: 'por',
        group: 'p8',
    },
    {
        brand: 'merc',
        group: 'p44',
    },
    {
        brand: 'bmw',
        group: 'p42',
    },
    {
        brand: 'cri',
        group: 'p88',
    },
    {
        brand: 'merc',
        group: 'p47',
    },
    {
        brand: 'bmw',
        group: 'p49',
    },
    {
        brand: 'ras',
        group: 'p34',
    },
    {
        brand: 'zen',
        group: 'p22',
    },
];

const isAdjacent = (array, brand1, brand2) => {
    return array.some((item, i) => {
        return (
            item.brand === brand1 &&
            ((array[i - 1] && array[i - 1].brand === brand2) || (array[i + 1] && array[i + 1].brand === brand2))
        );
    });
};

console.log(isAdjacent(arr, 'merc', 'bmw'));
console.log(isAdjacent(arr, 'merc', 'ras'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution , may i know how could i do this if property contains/includes `merc` or `bmw` , ifor e.g: `brand : 'mercedez'`

Comment: @Codenewbie, To check contains use `includes()` instead of `===`. Use like this way. `item.brand.includes(brand1)`

Comment: @Karan my bad didn't strike for me... thanks mate :)